# SAS proc sql passthrough running indefinitely

Tags: sql-server, sas, where-clause, proc-sql

I have some data in week-date-time format ie 14dec2020:00:00:00:000. I am using SAS and a proc sql (SQL Server) pass through query

This data contains many weeks worth of data but I was curious if theres in way to only pull data relevant to only current week? IE today is 17dec2020 so I would want to only pull data for the week of 14dec2020. if today was 22dec2020 then I would want it to pull data for the week of 21dec2020.

```
Data macros;
    today = today();
    wkday = weekday(today);
    start = today()-(wkday-1);
    end = today+(7-wkday);
    length cstart cend $22;
    cstart = "'" || put(start, date9.) || ':00:00:00.000' || "'";
    cend = "'" || put(end, date9.) || ':00:00:00.000' || "'";
    call symput ('start', cstart);
    call symput('end', cend);
run;
proc sql;  
    connect to odbc (dsn='x' uid='y' pwd='z');
    create table work.pleasehelp as select * from connection to odbc 
        (select Year, Month, Week, store, sales, SKU
            from datatable
            Where (&start. <= Week and week <= &end.)
            order by SKU);
    disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

There macros data set returns the proper date boundaries but when it tries running the PROC SQL it runs indefinitely. I ran it for 16 minutes and it only had a CPU run time of 1.09 seconds on it. I've tried changing the `cstart` and `cend` to just start and end throughout the queries but that runs with no matches.

Any help here would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the pass through running in ? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc...

Comment: SQL Server. I will update that in my notes. Thank you!

Comment: and what are the values in `datatable` columns `year` `month` and `week` ? Are they SQL Server date types who values are the start of the represented interval ? Is `datatable` a view ? What result set do you see if you execute the same passthrough query in a tool such a SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) ?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response here with the holidays but year is a four digit number, month is a digit 1-12 and then week is the 14dec2020:00:00:00:000 mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code will LOG what the SAS generated pass through query is.  Try performing the same query is a SQL Server tool.

```
%let start=;
%let end=;

data _null_;
    last_sunday = intnx('week', today(), 0);
    next_sunday = last_sunday + 7;

    call symput('last_sunday', quote(put(last_sunday, yymmdd10.),"'")); 
    call symput('next_sunday', quote(put(next_sunday, yymmdd10.),"'")); 
run;

/* The source code in the macro variables is
   'yyyy-mm-dd'
   and will be understood by SQL Server to be an ISO8601 standard date value
 */
%put &=last_sunday;
%put &=next_sunday;

/* This macro has SQL NOEXEC so you can see in the LOG window what
   the pass through query is.  Try running the same query in a
   SQL Server tool to see what the expected result set is
 */

%macro query;

proc sql noexec;
    connect to odbc (dsn=x uid=y pwd=z);
    create table work.pleasehelp as
    select * from connection to odbc
    ( select Year, Month, Week, store, sales, SKU
      from datatable
      where &last_sunday <= Week and Week < &next_sunday
            order by SKU
        );
    disconnect from odbc;
quit;

%mend;

options mprint;
%query;
```

Log window

```
MPRINT(QUERY):   create table work.pleasehelp as select * from connection to odbc (
```

**`select Year,
Month, Week, store, sales, SKU from datatable where '2020-12-27' <= Week and Week < '2021-01-03'
order by SKU`**

```
 );
NOTE: Statement not executed due to NOEXEC option.
```